# Horizontal dropdown menu on Opera

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, opera

I have problem with displaying dropdown menu on my site: http://lotzen.eu/jkowalczuk/
I works fine on most browsers: Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari

Problem starts on Opera. Links disappear when mouse is over the menu item.

I'm new in CSS and i can'f find any solution to this problem. Could someone please help?

Comment: Try to add `#nav ul { top: 29px; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `display` value to `inline-block` in your `class #nav li` and it's done.

```
#nav li {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

see the screenshot [here](http://d.pr/i/PVxj)